# Limit git-stash show to certain pathspec

Tags: git

I want to display a patch for a single file of a certain stash. Usually with `git-diff` you can append the `-- <pathspec>` to limit the output.

Now the `git-stash` manpage states the following for the `show` command...

```
By default, the command shows the diffstat, but it will accept
any format known to git diff
```

... but unfortunately it does not accept a trailing pathspec, so the following command won't work

```
$ git stash show -p --include-untracked stash@{0} -- test/foo.txt                   
Too many revisions specified: 'stash@{0}' 'test/foo.txt'
```

**The reason I want to use `git-stash` for this is because it has the `--include-untracked` option**. Is there a way to limit the output to a specific pathspec, or emulate the behavior of

```
git stash show -p --include-untracked stash@{0}
```

with a regular `git-diff` call?

Comment: Yes, the default for `git stash show` is to diff <rev> vs <rev>^ where <rev> is the "w" (working tree) commit for the stash, whose hash ID is the one you get with `git rev-parse refs/stash`. You can just write `stash^ stash` as the two commit hash IDs passed to `git diff` here. Note that `--include-untracked` (used at stash creation time) just creates a *third* commit in the stash for these files; that's `stash^3`, with `stash^2` holding the index commit. Commit `stash^3` has no parent (so there's nothing to diff against).

Comment: `git stash show` is learning or has learned to accept pathspecs in Git 2.36 or later, I believe. However, Git 2.36 has acquired some bugs when dealing with pathspecs and `git diff`, so you might want to hold off on using the new feature until all the bugs are ironed out. :-)

Comment: If what you want is to list out (or show) the "u" commit's files within some particular directory, consider diffing it against the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452). That is, if you've made the name `empty` for the empty tree, `git diff empty stash^3 -- <pathspec>` will produce such a diff. Every file will be added from scratch, though, so `--name-only` might be more useful.

Comment: It has to work for any stash, not just untracked or regular. `git diff <empty> stash^3` won't work on regular stashes unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to test the stash to see if `stash^3` exists to determine whether it's a two-commit (no untracked files) or three-commit (untracked files) stash.

Comment: But there is also a 3rd option, where the stash contains tracked and untracked files. Diffing against `stash^3` won't work for those. You'd essentially have to make 2 diffs and combine them (which is what `--include-untracked` does I think).

Comment: All stashes contain tracked files: that's what the i (index) and w (working tree) commits are. *Some* stashes *also* contain *untracked* files. And yes, it takes two `git diff` invocations here (which is why it's kind of broken in Git 2.36, which releases pathspecs after running one diff).